# Jquery closest method and append method for Task List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jquery. Have a project like Task List on the web.
I trying to remove the product from in progress div and insert into complete div and vice versa.
But have a problem when I find an object via `.closest()` I unable to append some HTML div, but `.remove()` work correctly.

How I can append some HTML else? or what wrong I do?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
    var product_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var complete = $(this).closest('#complete');
    var progress = $(this).closest('#progress');
    var prod = $(this).closest('#product');
    //console.log(product_id);
    var data = ' <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter"><div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + product_id + '"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="' + product_id + '"></label></div>';
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //data is already html product div
      prod.remove();
      complete.append(data);
      //console.log('done check in');

    } else {
      prod.remove();
      progress.append(data);
      //console.log('done check OUT');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datess">16-11-20
  <div id="progress" class="in-progress">In progress
    <div id="Marja">
      <h4>
        <p class="badge badge-secondary">
          Marja
        </p>
      </h4>
      <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
        product1
        <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="102">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="102"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end product-info-->
  </div>
  <!--e-co-product-->
  <hr class="divider">
  <div id="complete" class="complete">Сomplete
    <div id="Juh">
      <h4>
        <p class="badge badge-secondary">
          Juh
        </p>
      </h4>
      <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
        product2
        <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="103" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="103"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end product-info-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--product-->
<hr class="divider">
<hr class="divider">
<div class="datess">17-11-20
  <div id="progress" class="in-progress">In progress
    <div id="Marja">
      <h4>
        <p class="badge badge-secondary">
          Marja
        </p>
      </h4>
      <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
        product1
        <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="102">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="102"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end product-info-->
  </div>
  <!--e-co-product-->
  <hr class="divider">
  <div id="complete" class="complete">Сomplete
    <div id="Juh">
      <h4>
        <p class="badge badge-secondary">
          Juh
        </p>
      </h4>
      <div id="product" class="col-lg-3 no-gutter">
        product2
        <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="103" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="103"></label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end product-info-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `var th = $(this).closest('input:checkbox');` ? `$(this)` already IS an input:checkbox at that point? Do you have an input:checkbox inside an input:checkbox or something?

Comment: @TKoL no it just out-of-use variable,  sorry I delete this.

Comment: Hi, instead of `$(this).closest('#complete')` simply use `$('#complete')` and same for other div as well. Your checkbox will get only closest div where checkbox is not other div that's why append doesn't work.

Comment: @Swati I need to use closest because I one page may be more than 1 day, it will look like 
16-11-20-> in progress/complete and 17-11-20 in-progress/complete

i edit my question a bit

Comment: I see then use `$(this).closest(".datess").find('.complete')` and `$(this).closest(".datess").find('.progress')`   as your outer div is `datess` so you can  use that as `closest` also use `class` selector instead of `id` .

Comment: @Swati yeah all right it's work, but now have an issue that new drawed *product*  from versa list doesn't remove -_-.  (of couse changed `ready` to `$(document).on('change', ':checkbox', (function (e) {`)

Comment: @Swati sorry all fine, if wanna can send the answer on this question for rate